# Does gfortran support tail call elimination?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, tail-recursion

I made this small program to test, if gfortran does tail call elimination:

```
program tailrec
implicit none

print *, tailrecsum(5, 0)

contains

recursive function tailrecsum (x, running_total) result (ret_val)
    integer, intent(in) :: x
    integer, intent(in) :: running_total
    integer             :: ret_val

    if (x == 0) then
        ret_val = running_total
        return
    end if
    ret_val = tailrecsum (x-1, running_total + x)
end function tailrecsum

end program
```

To check, I compiled it with the -S option, to take a look at the instructions. Here the lines for the tailrecsum function:

```
tailrecsum.3429:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .L2
    movl    (%rsi), %eax
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:
    subq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    leal    -1(%rax), %edx
    addl    (%rsi), %eax
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
    leaq    12(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    %edx, 8(%rsp)
    movl    %eax, 12(%rsp)
    call    tailrecsum.3429
    addq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

At the end, I see `call tailrecsum.3429` and therefore, think that there is no tail call elimination. This is the same also when I use `-O2` or `-O3` and `-foptimize-sibling-calls`.
So, does gfortran not support this or is it a problem of my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does support it. It is quite tricky to avoid many very subtle traps which harm the tail call optimization.

---

It becomes simpler for the compiler to optimize tail calls if you pass the arguments by value. In that case there is no temporary to which the receiving procedure needs to have a pointer (address).

In fact, this modification is enough to get the tail call elimination and enable unlimited recursion:

```
recursive function tailrecsum (x, running_total) result (ret_val) bind(C)
    integer, value :: x
    integer, value :: running_total
    integer             :: ret_val

    if (x == 0) then
        ret_val = running_total
        return
    end if
    ret_val = tailrecsum (x-1, running_total + x)
end function tailrecsum
```

Gfortran does not require the `bind(C)` because it implements all `value` as C-like pass by value. Intel does require it because it creates a temporary and passes its address.

The details may differ on different architectures, depending on who is responsible for the cleanup of what.

---

Consider this version:

```
program tailrec
use iso_fortran_env

implicit none

integer(int64) :: acc, x

acc = 0

x = 500000000

call tailrecsum(x, acc)

print *, acc

contains

recursive subroutine tailrecsum (x, running_total)
    integer(int64), intent(inout) :: x
    integer(int64), intent(inout) :: running_total
    integer(int64)             :: ret_val

    if (x == 0)  return
    
    running_total = running_total + x
    x = x - 1
    call tailrecsum (x, running_total)
end subroutine tailrecsum



end program
```

With 500000000 iterations it would clearly blow the stack without TCO, but it does not:

```
> gfortran -O2 -frecursive tailrec.f90 
> ./a.out 
   125000000250000000
```

You can examine what the compiler does more easily using `-fdump-tree-optimized`. Honestly, I didn't even bother trying to understand your assembly output. X86 assembly is simply too esoteric for me, my simple brain can handle only certain RISCs.

You can see that there is still a lot going on after the call to the next iteration in your original version:

```
  <bb 6>:
  _25 = _5 + -3;
  D.1931 = _25;
  _27 = _18 + _20;
  D.1930 = _27;
  ret_val_28 = tailrecsum (&D.1931, &D.1930);
  D.1930 ={v} {CLOBBER};
  D.1931 ={v} {CLOBBER};

  <bb 7>:
  # _29 = PHI <_20(5), ret_val_28(6)>

  <bb 8>:
  # _22 = PHI <_11(4), _29(7)>

  <bb 9>:
  # _1 = PHI <ret_val_7(3), _22(8)>
  return _1;

}
```

I am not an expert in GIMPLE, but the `D.193x` operations are definitely linked to the temporary expressions that are put on the stack for the call.

The `PHI` operations then find which version of the return value will be actually returned based on which branch was actually taken in the if statement (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/SSA.html).

As I said it is sometimes tricky to simplify your code to the right form which is acceptable for gfortran to perform the tail call optimization.

Comment: Thank you! I am experimenting some more and `gfortran -foptimize-sibling-calls tailrec.f90` is not enough to make it work (-> segfaults). `-O1` does not work either. Looking at the assembly of the `-O2` version, it looks as if the whole function has been inlined into main...
... okai, `-O1 -foptimize-sibling-calls` is working!

Comment: Yes, it is inlined, but you can compile it separately and you will see it is full of GOTOs but it does not contains any call.

Comment: Okai, now I want to know why using `-foptimize-sibling-calls` is not enough. So, I am trying different combinations of the options that come with `-O1` at the moment...

Comment: Strange thing is: using `-O1 -foptimize-sibling-calls` works, but `-foptimize-sibling-calls` and then all the `-O1` options explicitly does not.

Comment: I think `-foptimize-sibling-calls` is only needed for indirect recursion.