# Tail call optimization in ifort vs gfortran

Tags: assembly, gcc, fortran, intel-fortran, tail-call-optimization

I have some code that when is compiled with gfortran, a tail call optimization is done, but when compiled with ifort, it isn't.

Here are some very simple snips describing the issue:

[gfortran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDz8i.png)

[ifort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyY0O.png)

Therefore, the code

```
function f(a, b)
    real, intent(in) :: a, b
    real :: f
    f = a**b
end function f
```

is compiled using gfortran to:

```
f_:
    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rsi]
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    jmp     powf
```

and using ifort to:

```
f_:
    push      rsi                                           #1.10
    movss     xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi]                         #4.10
    movss     xmm1, DWORD PTR [rsi]                         #4.10
    call      powf                                          #4.10
    pop       rcx                                           #5.1
    ret                                                     #5.1
```

I expected both compilers to do the tail call optimization, and I used -O3 compiler flag in both.

I looked online but couldn't find a similar issue. I only found this: [Does gfortran support tail call elimination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330498/does-gfortran-support-tail-call-elimination) but here gfortran fails to do the optimization and the code is much more complicated.

Why doesn't ifort do the tail call optimization?

[EDIT]:
[vtune output of my original code (not the simplified version above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqjeb.png)

[EDIT]:
Here is a usage example of f:

```
program calling_func

real :: res

res = 0.d0

do i = 1, 10000
    res = res + f(real(mod(i,3)), real(mod(i,3)))
end do
Print *, res

end program calling_func

function f(a, b)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: a, b
    real :: f
    f = a**b
end function f
```

on gfortran, the line `f = a**b` is converted in assemebly to `jmp pow` while in ifort to `call pow`.

Comment: ifort is indeed faster than gfortran in this case. I can try to construct my exact usage, but I'm not trying to make things run faster in this particular case. I'm just trying to understand what causes the compilers to behave differently.

Comment: OK, I see we can see the difference even even compiled in isolation as in https://godbolt.org/z/4e5zvf or https://godbolt.org/z/5dxbMM The diference just may stem from the `powf` function itself.

Comment: It is probably better to just look at the C call https://godbolt.org/z/G4P6qz https://godbolt.org/z/sG4jK4 I adjusted the tags to perhaps attract the right experts.

Comment: Thanks! what do you mean by "The diference just may stem from the `powf` function itself"?

Comment: Intel and GCC have different runtime libraries, but that probably does not matter. I am not good at assembly.

Comment: Are you sure the asm difference isn't ifort auto-vectorizing? It's good at that, and its default FP model is "fast", somewhat like `gfortran -ffast-math`.  I'd hope `f()` would inline into the calling loop so tailcall or not wouldn't matter for the performance of the main loop.

Comment: I'm copiling with -no-vec so vectorization shouldn't be done. Moreover, `f` is not simd enabled. As I've seen on the assembly, `f` is not inlined - how will inlining it affect the performance? There will still be a call for pow() and not jump...

Comment: I may be missing the thrust of the question, but I would be trying to make the function "f" be ELEMENTAL as my second step after adding IMPLICIT NONE to the main program..

Comment: I talk mainly about `f`. Making `f` elemental still have'nt solved this issue. Moreover, this issue exists in c too as @Vladimir F showed above. The point of the question is "why do the different compilers generate different assembly for `f`, and why does gfortran do optimization which ifort doesn't?"

Comment: The implicit idea of elemental is that one may recover some speed, and then not be as concerned with what is happening at the assembly/machine-code level. So in a pragmatic sense, using elemental, then makes sense as a solution to recover some lost speed. However if tt is more of an academic question, then whether things are passed by reference or value, may also come into play. BIND(C) may also provide some help in stack versus heap, and well as whether arrays are in heap or the stack.

Comment: I wasn't able to add bind(c) due to polymorphism, but anyways, the question is relevant to c too, so it still doesn't solve the issue